# Correct way to lock the dictionary object

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locking, syncroot

In my code I have a static dictionary object

```
private static IDictionary< ConnKey, DbConnection > ConnectionList = new Dictionary< ConnKey, DbConnection >( );
```

which is throwing this error

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
```

I searched and found that this occurs because multiple threads try to access dictionary, but I do have `lock` on dictionary

```
lock( ConnectionList ) {
   ConnectionList.Add( key, res );
}
```

Then I searched more and found that lock on dictionary doesn't prevent all the operations on it so I should be using `lock` on `SyncRoot` object of it like this to achieve what I want

```
lock( ((IDictionary)ConnectionList).SyncRoot) {
```

But then I searched that using `SyncRoot` is not a good practice

On further search I found there is a `ConcurrentDictionary` for this purpose

1. So can anybody please suggest me which is the best way to lock the dictionary
2. If I use `ConcurrentDictionary` do I still need to use `lock` on it or will it handle everything by itself.
3. If I have to use lock on `ConcurrentDictionary`, I have to use `lock` on it directly or again I have to lock the `SyncRoot` object for it

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With `Dictionary<,>` you have to lock both reading and writing. So both

```
lock( ConnectionList ) {
   ConnectionList.Add( key, res );
}
```

and

```
lock( ConnectionList ) {
   res = ConnectionList[ key ];
}
```

and

```
lock( ConnectionList ) {
   int cnt = ConnectionList.Count;
}
```

and

```
lock( ConnectionList ) {
   ConnectionList.Clear();
}
```

and

```
lock( ConnectionList ) {
   foreach ( var kv in ConnectionList ) {
      // Do things
   }
}
```

and so on :-)

With `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` you don't need any locking, but note that the syntax is a little different than the one of the `Dictionary<,>`

Comment: Thanks! So you mean everytime I access the dictionary I should lock it first and If I do that it will become thread safe, right?

Comment: @PawanNogariya Yep. **Any** and **all** access must be in a `lock`. There are no methods/properties that are connected to accessing the data in the `Dictionary<,>` that are guaranteed to be thread safe (with *that are connected to accessing* I mean that `.GetType()` and similar methods are still thread safe, but not very useful for using a `Dictionary<,>` :-) )

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't it make code ugly if I have to access the dictionary frequently, in that case will you suggest `ConcurrentDictionary` over this method and I never have to lock it, right?
And its just the syntax difference, right?

Comment: @PawanNogariya It all depends on how you want to use the `Dictionary<>`. If you will have concurrent reads and writes then `ConcurrentDictionary<>` is better. But if, for example, you have only an initial multithreaded load phase and when it finishes you only read, then using the `lock` is better. Note that if there are only readers, then `Dictionary<>` is thread safe. See Thread Safety in https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx: *A Dictionary<TKey, TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.*

Comment: @JayShah The exact explanation is complex, the easiest way to imagine it is that to make a read to a dictionary, there are multiple steps done inside the `Dictionary<,>` class. The fact that there are multiple steps means that it could be not-thread-safe

Answer (score 3):

> 1. So can anybody please suggest me which is the best way to lock the dictionary

You can use it's `SyncRoot` or create a private object that you lock when accessing the dictionary object, e.g.

```
private static object _sybcRoot = new object();

public static void Add( string key, string res)
    lock( _sybcRoot ) {
       ConnectionList.Add( key, res );
    }
}
```

You have to use *the same* lock object to guard the access to the *same* resource. Otherwise threads may "think" the resource is free, whereas in reality it is used by the other thread which just happen to lock it on the other object's sync root.

> 2. If I use ConcurrentDictionary do I still need to use lock on it or will it handle everything by itself.

No, there is no need for locking when using any `Concurrent*` collection. It is thread-safe by design, but this syntax is slightly different. `Concurrent*` collections use lockless approach, which is better in a situations when you don't have many threads competing for access (optimistic concurrency)

> 3. If I have to use lock on ConcurrentDictionary, I have to use lock on it directly or again I have to lock the SyncRoot object for it

Comment: Is there any problem if I lock on ConnectionList instead of using separate _sybcRoot  object ?

Answer (score 3):

> So can anybody please suggest me which is the best way to lock the dictionary?

if you want to continue  using the classic `Dictionary<,>`  AFAK you have to look to `ICollection` interface implemented  by  Dictionary and use  the property [`ICollection.SyncRoot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
which by  definition

**MSDN** 
  *`Gets an object that can be used to synchronize access to the ICollection.`* 
So to  achieve  this  you  can do  something like  this

> If I use ConcurrentDictionary do I still need to use lock on it or will it handle everything by itself.

From  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
*ConcurrentDictionary is designed for multithreaded scenarios. You do not have to use locks in your code to add or remove items from the collection. However, it is always possible for one thread to retrieve a value, and another thread to immediately update the collection by giving the same key a new value.*

> If I have to use lock on ConcurrentDictionary, I have to use lock on it directly or again I have to lock the SyncRoot object for it

Yes you  have to use `lock` on `SyncRoot` if you want to do Atomic methods execution  when you use `GetOrAdd`  or `AddOrUpdate` methods